# Win32 button appearance

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I'm working on a GUI for a chess program using Win32, and my first thought was to make the board an 8X8 grid of buttons. However, I would prefer the squares on my board to be solid, single colors with no additional visual frills, while I haven't found a way to create a button that doesn't have a border around it. Is it possible to alter the appearance of a button arbitrarily, or are the borders unavoidable? If the latter, what other implementation could I look into for rendering a board that looks exactly how I want?

Comment: Look into sub-classing controls and owner-draw controls.

Comment: Yes, you can draw every pixel.

Comment: The owner-drawn controls look like they're probably exactly what I need. I swear I looked around the documentation before asking, but haven't found it very intuitive to find things in when I don't know the name of what I'm looking for going in.

Comment: Don't use a button. Paint your entire board directly. GUI controls are a good fit.

Comment: @David Is there a specific kind of Win32 entity called a GUI control the same way there is one called a button? I'm not finding one searching for it on msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: Nope. Don't use a windowed control for this.

Comment: You could make the board as a collection of windows; they don't need the extra features of a button.  They are fundamentally windows, just small ones.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: What benefit do you get by creating 8x8 small windows instead of creating a single window that renders the entire board?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know about Thomas's reasons, but the problem I'd have with making the board a single window is that I haven't found a way to make a window that isn't further divided into child controls do different things depending on where you click on it.

Comment: You code that logic yourself. You have to relate the window coordinates to the board coordinates. It's simple math.

Comment: @David I agree that that's a conceptually simple idea, and it's the kind of thing I was imagining when I asked about whether there's another implementation I could use, but I don't know the semantics for referring to coordinates or causing messages to trigger outside of the context of controls. I haven't gotten very for with Win32 yet, and find it difficult to locate what's relevant to me in the documentation.

Comment: It's going to be tough without experience.

Comment: @David I'm open to the idea that this project relies on too many prerequisites I don't have to be worth pursuing right now, but I have to start somewhere.

Comment: It's going to be far harder for you to code it using windowed controls for each square. This I know from my own experience. But in your position, you'll only learn by having your own experiences. Do it one way, then the other, and see what you learn.

Comment: Unless you are doing animations where a piece moves from one square to the next, using buttons is fine and you don't have to do your own hit-testing. Either way, it should only take a few minutes to try both a big surface and individual controls...

Answer (score 2):

Create the buttons with the [`BS_OWNERDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951(v=vs.85).aspx) style and handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message.